# how to loop through a nested array, and preserve the array structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I currently have an array of arrays thats look like this:

```
[Array(8), Array(5), Array(7), Array(13), Array(9), Array(5), Array(4), Array(10)]
```

each array has objects in them, and each object has a various values.

what i'm looking to do is loop through the whole array, and then in each array, I want to grab a value from each object in the array. I havent had a problem doing that, but the problem I have come across was preserving the original structure.

I essentially want to keep all the arrays how they are, but instead of showing the entire object, I want to just show the one value that I need from the object.

```
for (let i = 0, len = item.length; i < len; i++) {
        temp = item[i];
        for (let i = 0, len = temp.length; i < len; i++) {
             array.push(temp[i].item);
         }
     }
```

this is my code, problem is, I get a list of all the items in one single array instead of in the their original format.

Comment: the array structure will be preserved in looping. Please share your code

Comment: updated sorry been busy @brk

Comment: Your loop doesn't modify the array or create a new one, you are only logging the value. What exactly are you trying to do? Build an array of arrays that contain the `name` property from the originals?

Comment: Your edit doesn't help. You don't manipulate anything. Everything stays as it is.

Comment: Thats where I need help, im only logging the value because I dont know what to do at that point. Im logging the correct value, but I need those values to be put in the original arrays with nothing else. @chazsolo

Comment: but...you're logging all values. i don't see any conditional. Try to give more information. Show a little snippet of the array structure you have, and what output you expect in the end.

Comment: the array structure is what you see at the top. An array of arrays, with a certain amount of objects inside each one. All i want to do, is loop through the each array, and grab a certain value from each object inside the arrays, and essentially just have the values end up being the only thing in the arrays. Example, array 1: has 8 objects inside. 8 objects with 8 values that I need. I want the final array to be the 8 values of those objects.  @chazsolo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope i got your question right.
if so you can do it with

### lodash

```
const currentArray = [[{name: 'foo'},{name: 'bar'},{name: 'bar'}], [{name: 'foo'},{name: 'foo'},{name: 'bar'}]];

const newArray = _.map(currentArray, innerArray => {

  return _.map(innerArray, obj => obj.name)
});

console.log(newArray);  //[['foo','bar','bar'],['foo','foo','bar']]
```

### **es6**

```
const currentArray= [[{name: 'foo'},{name: 'bar'},{name: 'bar'}], [{name: 'foo'},{name: 'foo'},{name: 'bar'}]];


const newArray = currentArray.map(innerArray => {

  return innerArray.map(obj => obj.name)
});

console.log(newArray); //[['foo','bar','bar'],['foo','foo','bar']]
```

Comment: perfection exactly what was needed

Comment: happy to help :)